# Editing/Removing contacts from iPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts

I've accumulated 1000+ contacts over the years and multiple iPhone upgrades. Is there any way to remove contacts quickly either on the phone or from my Mac while syncing?

(A decade ago, the Blackberry, company issued, synced with outlook. So I didn't edit on the BB at all. Does the iPhone sync to a program on the Desktop Mac, and I've just not noticed?)

iPhone5, MacPro running 10.6.8 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent OS X, you can enable iCloud so that the contacts are synced to the Contacts.app on the mac. If you are either unable or unwilling to upgrade OS X, you can also edit the contacts on icloud.com, provided iCloud & its contacts syncing option is enabled on your iPhone.

Comment: I'm looking at $1600+ in replacement cost for software that right now is running on Snow-Leo. Not complaining, it's just enough that I'll keep this OS for my main drive for now.  The cloud option is perfect, about 1/20 the time per delete. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer If you just want to delete and not edit, there are some apps in the app store that will let you do that (e.g search for contacts delete or contacts clean up).

Comment: Thanks again, but this is a one time project, and over 1/3 of the way through already.